# MVC3 with Ninject Error: MVCApplication does not implement inherited abstract member

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

This is my first time trying to use Ninject so I am probably doing this wrong. Here is what I have done so far and the error I am getting:

1. Created a new MVC3 application called TestApplication.
2. Downloaded (via NuGet) Ninject v2.2.1.4 and Ninject.MVC3 v2.2.2.0
3. Changed System.Web.HttpApplication to NinjectHttpApplication on line 14 of the Global.asax file.
4. Built the application.

This resulted in the following error:

**Error 1   'TestApplication.MvcApplication' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectHttpApplication.CreateKernel()'**

I have not altered the App_Start>NinjectMVC3.cs code.

What do I need to do to clear the error? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to inherit your Application from NinjectHttpApplication.  Ninject.MVC3 provides all the hookup required.  You just add your bindings to the App_Start/NinjectMVC3.cs file.

Comment: Yes this indeed worked for the NuGet package installation. I have also put back the inherit on the Global.asax to **System.Web.HttpApplication**.